# How to move a variable from one of my textbox to a public bool I setup

Tags: c#

So im pretty new and this made be a dumb question but im trying to take this variable ive made within my textbox and move it into a bool that i made and im really not getting it.
Here is the first little snipit that shows what variable im trying to get.

```
   public FixTheDomain()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FixTheDomain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Pass_Textbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Pass; 
        Pass = PassTextbox.Text;\\this is the variable i want

    }
```

And i want to put it into this bool

```
 public static bool ValidateUser()
    {


       bool validation;
        try
        {
            LdapConnection lcon = new LdapConnection
                    (new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName,
                                 variablegoeshere,Environment.UserDomainName);
            lcon.Credential = nc;
            lcon.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
            // user has authenticated at this point,
            // as the credentials were used to login to the dc.
            lcon.Bind(nc);
            validation = true;
        }
        catch (LdapException)
        {
            validation = false;
        }
        return validation;
    }
```

Comment: How `ValidateUser()` is called? It's `static`, so in theory you can use static field, but ... And what event handler is `Pass_Textbox()` ?

Comment: ValidateUser() will be used on a button click in my form but inorder for me to have that piece work in need that Pass variable into here NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName,
                                 variablegoeshere,Environment.UserDomainName);

Comment: Man, change the name to "Password". Driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass values between methods, the most common technique is using [parameters](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/function-parameters/).

So for your method:

```
public static bool ValidateUser(string pass)
{
    bool validation;
    try
    {
        LdapConnection lcon = new LdapConnection
                (new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName,
                             pass,Environment.UserDomainName);
        lcon.Credential = nc;
        lcon.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
        // user has authenticated at this point,
        // as the credentials were used to login to the dc.
        lcon.Bind(nc);
        validation = true;
    }
    catch (LdapException)
    {
        validation = false;
    }
    return validation;
}
```

And in your caller:

```
public void Pass_Textbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Pass; 
    Pass = PassTextbox.Text;\\this is the variable i want
    ValidateUser(Pass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `ValidateUser` method so that it takes a parameter of type `string`.

```
public static bool ValidateUser(string pass)
{
   bool validation;
   try
   {
       LdapConnection lcon = new LdapConnection
               (new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
       NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName,
                            pass,Environment.UserDomainName);
       lcon.Credential = nc;
       lcon.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
       // user has authenticated at this point,
       // as the credentials were used to login to the dc.
       lcon.Bind(nc);
       validation = true;
   }
   catch (LdapException)
   {
       validation = false;
   }
   return validation;
}
```

You can then call it and pass it the parameter:

```
string Pass; 
Pass = PassTextbox.Text;

bool validation = ValidateUser(Pass);
```